How to Run back-to-back macros in Excel (Textboxes keep pausing macros)
Just wanted to know how to run back-to-back macros in excel, I know the basic way to do it but the macros im running pop up a textbox when it is finished running which I have to click "Ok" on before the next one will execute.
Ive already tried "SendKeys" and vbmodeless but neither of those seems to work.

And you can't modify the macros itself to prevent the message boxes?

I have thought of that and I think I have tried, what command would you use to do that and where would you place it? I might have been using the wrong one

This is not a single command that you place. You need to find the instance(s) in your code where the command MsgBox is issued and either remove it, put it into a comment or do something like If ShowMessages The MsgBox(...) instead (and define a variable or parameter named ShowMessages that you set to True or False depending on if you want to show the messages or not.

Could we see the code?  Do you mean a text box (inputbox maybe) or a message box?

Is there any line of code I could make so when I run the all macros command it suppressed message boxes?

No such command exists.

its just a msgbox command that says "data updated"

As @FunThomas suggested then - I'd just comment it out (place a ' at the start of the line).

Next time the msgBox appears, press [Ctrl]+[Break]. You should see a message "Code execution has been interrupted". Press Debug. The VBA editor will show you the code where the "MsgBox"-command is issued. Just put a comment sign (a sinqle quote character ') in front of it and it will no longer appear.

This code can replace the standard MsgBox with a self destructing MsgBox.
Firstly, you'll need to find all calls to MsgBox and replace them with myMsgBox. You can use Search/Replace for this.
Then add the following to your code:
Function myMsgBox(Prompt As String, _
                Optional Buttons As Integer, _
                Optional Title As String = "Microsoft Excel", _
                Optional Helpfile As String = "", _
                Optional Context As String = "", _
                Optional myMsgBox_Delay As Integer = 5)
    Set myMsgBoxShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    myMsgBox = myMsgBoxShell.Popup(Prompt, _
                myMsgBox_Delay, Title, Buttons)
End Function

You can change the myMsgBox_Delay As Integer = 5 to a different number of seconds if you need to.
